# How to store independent key value pairs in redis?

Tags: python, redis

I have a requirement where I would like to store two or more independent sets of key value pairs in Redis. they are required to be independent because they represent completely different datasets.

For example, consider the following independent kv sets:

1. Mapping between user_id and corresponding session_id
2. Mapping between game lobby id and corresponding host's user_id
3. Mapping between user_id and usernames

Now, if I had to store this key values "in memory" using some data structure in Python, I would user 3 separate `dict`s (or `HashMap`s in Java). But how can I achieve this in Redis? The separation is required because for almost all user_ids there will be session_id as well as username.

I'm referring this Redis doc for available datatypes: https://redis.io/topics/data-types and the closest match with my requirements is `Hash`. But as mentioned, they are objects and only space efficient if there are a few fields. So is this okay to store huge amounts of kv pairs? Will that impact search time going forward?

Are there any alternatives to achieve this using Redis? I'm completely new to Redis.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating separate databases (sometimes Redis calls them 'key-spaces') for each of your data sets. Then you create your connection/pool objects with the `db` parameter:

```
>>> pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='redis_host', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

The only drawback of this is that you need to then manage different pools for each data set. Another (perhaps easier) option is to just add a tag to the keys that indicate which data set they belong to.

Also worth noting that the key-spaces are organized numerically (so you can't name them like in other database systems), and it only supports a small number (I think 15).

As for the number of K-V pairs, it's completely fine to store huge numbers of them, and lookups should still be pretty quick. O(1) lookup is the main advantage of key-based data structures, with the tradeoff being that you are limited (to some extent anyway) to using the key to access the data (as opposed to other databases where you can query on any field in the table).

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the answer. +1. So there are no alternatives other than separate databases? This seems to be a very common requirement.

Comment: The other option is to add a tag to the keys that will allow them to be separated by the data set they belong to. If the keys are strings, it might be as simple as adding a prefix "<dataset_name>_<key>". Depending on how you'll be using it, you could also key the data based on a derived numeric key value, (but that's really not much different than adding a prefix). Any scheme is ultimately going to have to guarantee that the keys are unique.